# What does progressAnimation，ev and C minClickBlockDuration in the parameter ionic3 in navOption?

Tags: ionic-framework, nav

I don't know what NavOptions' `progressAnimation`, `minClickBlockDuration` and `ev` do when I am using

```
this.navCtrl.push (page: Page | string, params? Any, opts? NavOptions, done? Function)
```

in ionic3